# Why the following code gives this output?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I was tweaking with the `printf()` function.Since the `printf()` function takes a format specifier in order to recognize the datatype to print(Correct me if i'm wrong) the value of the datatype passed into it as argument,so I tried to do something like this---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *f="%d";
char *g="asd";

printf(f,g);
return 0;
}
```

And the o/p is--

> 4210739

I am unable to understand why o/p is a number ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You're trying to print a *string* using `%d` format specifier. You should be using `%s` format specifier instead. Using wrong type of argument for a particular format (conversion) specifier invokes UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Change

```
char *f="%d";
```

to

```
char *f="%s";
```

Comment: This is certainly not undefined behavior.  The format %d tells the printf() statement to treat the argument as if it was an integer.  It's quite happy to treat a pointer (a memory address) as an integer.  The number it's printing is the address of `g`

Comment: @Tibrogargan so you're basically saying, the C standard is wrong? Wow...What a day!!

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh no, your interpretation is wrong.  A memory address is usually a perfectly correct type for a %d conversion specification

Comment: @Tibrogargan and, the availability of `%p` is a waste, no? We can simply use `%d` then.... (__please don't__).

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh It's not *standard*, it is however *implementation defined*, certainly not undefined.  How this is treated is 100% defined, depending on the implementation

Comment: @Tibrogargan; The only correct specifier for an address (pointer type) is `%p`.

Comment: I think the therm undefined means because is platform depend not the C library itself, for example: is undefined the use %p in **strftime**, the output is undefined in some machines...that's my way of interpretate it.

Comment: @haccks His answer was that the *code invokes undefined behavior*, which is patently incorrect.  I agree that if you wanted to print a pointer, you should use %p, but that was not Sourav Ghosh's answer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - A system is allowed to pass pointers and integers (and floating point values) in different registers, without defining how it does that. Using the wrong format might print a value from the wrong register - totally undefined.

Comment: @haccks absolutely. Just to add, a casting to `void *` for the argument will make it prefect. :)

Comment: @Tibrogargan The standard says "the behavior is undefined". Or are you saying that there some other part of the standard that says "the behavior is implementation-defined"? Perhaps you mean "implementation-dependent"? (Implementation-defined has a specific meaning in the standard. This behavior cannot be defined on some implementations, such as the one Bo mentioned, or any implementation where `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int)`.)

Comment: @Bo Persson like a number of other people here, you are conflating "undefined" with "implementation-defined".  See the C Standard, subclause 6.3.2.3

Comment: @Tibrogargan; Yes. Code does invoke undefined behavior. Standard says it in paragraph **§7.21.6.1**: *If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @haccks depending on the implementation, a pointer *may be* a correct type for the %d conversion

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't see how 6.3.2.3 is relevant. There is no pointer-to-integer conversion taking place here. Variadic parameters undergo only default argument promotions. Pointer-to-integer is not a default argument promotion.

Comment: @Raymond Chen How the parameter is treated depends entirely on how printf is implemented (which is the point).  At some stage, printf will convert the value passed in into an integer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan; *Undefined behavior* is not *implementation defined behavior*.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Since you're talking about "implementation-defined" behaviour, let me add my two cents here. The definition of  "implementation-defined" starts with **"unspecified behavior....."** and clearly, US and UB ***are*** two different things.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Then your answer should say "unspecified behavior", not "undefined".  As is, it's misleading.  My whole point is that *Undefined behavior* is not *implementation defined behavior*

Comment: @Tibrogargan nopes, because for this case, standard mentions UB. I'm good with it. :)

Comment: The C standard states it is a undefined behavior, because not to force stdlib manufacturers to perform additional validation logic for printf(). And people should treat the situation as undefined behavior. But under the hood it is quite clear what the behavior is.

Comment: "At some stage, printf will convert the value passed in into an integer." Nowhere does the standard require that this conversion take place, and if it takes place, there's nothing in the standard that requires that it follow the rules of 6.3.2.3.

Comment: seems like this argument is about 2 different things to me. In a _particular system_ there is no such thing as undefined behavior. At least there better not be. Computers do what they do _because_ they are deterministic and they should _always_ be in a well-defined state. `c`, of course, is implemented on several architectures and systems. It's pretty clear to me that based on the 7.21.6.1 quoted section, `c` can't guarantee how this will behave. If the OP knows his system inside-out, then sure, the OPs code is very well defined. But across platforms, from `C`'s perspective, this is UB.

Comment: @yano There's a difference between undefined behavior and implementation defined behavior.  Behavior is undefined when it could change between executions on the same system.  Behavior is implementation defined when it changes from one platform to another but not between executions.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Well that makes sense too. I don't know enough to know if this would produce a different output on the same machine for different executions (guess some test code could answer that question for my machine),, doesn't seem like it would. But it's hard for me to argue with a direct quote from the standard.

Comment: @Tibrogargan But just to flesh out my previous point (though it may be off topic),, Even on a particular system, even if different executions produce different results, that's still not purely "undefined". It is undefined in the sense that "I don't know enough about what's going on under the hood to know what will happen", but if you had **all** the information about **everything** in that computer and the forces manipulating it, you could reliably predict the outcome of executed code **every single time**, even if the `C` standard says "this is UB"

Comment: heh,, but the real-world-application takeaway here is use `%d` for `int`s, `%p` for pointers, and `%s` for strings.

Comment: @yano whether or not this is undefined behavior depends entirely on your interpretation of "correct type".  Since C allows conversion of pointers to ints, is a pointer a correct type or not?  You might argue that it's not since it's unsigned and %d expects a signed value, or that it's not because you're on a 64 bit machine.  If you wanted to print an address some selection of %u, %llu or %llx might be more appropriate (or of course %p)

Comment: @yano The word "undefined" has a very specific meaning in the context of the C language. It means "The C standard does not make any requirements." You seem to be using it in a more informal sense to mean "unpredictable". It's a contradiction to say "This is not undefined even though the C standard says it is undefined." (It can still be unpredictable if it involves, say, reading uninitialized memory.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Right. I think some of us are missing the point, for US, spec __defines__ two or more possibilities and leave the __choice__ to the implementation, while, in case of UB, standard mentions **nothing.**.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated, the `%d` specifier specifies that you will be passing a integer as second parameter and you pass a pointer (`*char` typed) variable instead. So the `printf()` routine interprets the pointer as an integer and prints it (it's value actually) as so.

To correctly output the string, you should use the `%s` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> Since the printf() function takes a format specifier in order to recognize the datatype to print (Correct me if i'm wrong)

I'm not sure, but I think you may be a little wrong here.

When you call

```
printf(f, g);
```

the key thing to understand is that *`printf` has no way of knowing the type of `g`*.

When you call `printf`, it is *your* job to ensure that for every format specifier (that is, every `%` thingie) you use in the format string, you pass an argument of the correct type.  For each `%d` in your format string, you must pass an `int`. For each `%f` in your format string, you must pass a `double`. For each `%s` in your format string, you must pass a `char *` pointing to a valid string.  And so on.

In your code, you've got a `%d` in the format string, but instead of passing an `int`, you pass a `char *` pointing at a string.  So you don't get the result you expect.

The `%d` wanted an `int`, but you didn't give it one.  You passed a `char *`, but `printf` didn't know what to do with it.  (If you had used `%s`, then `printf` would have known what to do with the `char *`.)